# What's pylint's TypeVar name specification?

Tags: python, pylint, vscode-python

Pylint gives a warning whenever something like this happens:

```py
import typing

SEQ_FR = typing.TypeVar("SEQ_FR")
#^^^^^ gets underlined with the warning
```

The warning is like this: `Type variable name "SEQ_FR" doesn't conform to predefined naming style. pylint(invalid-name)`

I tried searching through Pylint's documentations with no luck on finding the exact regex / specifications used. Doesn't seem like I can pass a custom regex onto Pylint for this as well, unlike regular variables, methods, functions, classes, etc.

**What is the specification used by Pylint to flag TypeVar variables as valid or invalid names?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find the rule used in the [Pylint messages documentation](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/messages_overview.html); this error is named `invalid-name`, so the specific documentation can be found on the [*invalid-name / C0103* page](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/convention/invalid-name.html#predefined-naming-patterns), which has a `TypeVar` rule in the [*Predefined Naming Patterns* section](https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/convention/invalid-name.html):

> **Name type**: `typevar`
> **Good Names**: `T`, `_CallableT`, `_T_co`, `AnyStr`, `DeviceTypeT`, `IPAddressT`
> **Bad Names**: `DICT_T`, `CALLABLE_T`, `ENUM_T`, `DeviceType`, `_StrType`, `TAnyStr`

It doesn't document the exact regex rule here, but Pylint will actually include the regex used in the error message when you use the  `--include-naming-hint=y` command-line switch <sup>*)</sup>:

> `Type variable name "SEQ_FR" doesn't conform to predefined naming style ('^_{0,2}(?!T[A-Z])(?:[A-Z]+|(?:[A-Z]+[a-z]+)+T?(?<!Type))(?:_co(?:ntra)?)?$' pattern) (invalid-name)`

Alternatively, you can find the [regex for typevars in the source code](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/0cc82c4c0de8771c1323cc2e183497d722ea5bfe/pylint/checkers/base/name_checker/checker.py#L40-L44).

Breaking the pattern down, typevar names are compliant when following these rules:

- Optionally start with 0-2 underscores
- *not* starting with *T<capital letter>*
- either

  - all capital letters and no underscores,
  - or a *PascalCaseWord* <sup>✝)</sup> optionally ending in *T*, no underscores, and not ending with *Type*
- with an optional *_co* or *_contra* ending.

Put differently, typevar names must be either PascalCase <sup>✝)</sup> or all-caps, are optionally protected (`_`) or private (`__`), are optionally marked as covariant (`_co`) or contravariant (`_contra`), and should not end in *Type*.

A compliant name for your example could be `SeqFr` or `SeqFrT`; the `T` suffix is [meant to make it clear the SnakeCaseT name is a typevar](https://github.com/python/typeshed/issues/1872).

Alternatively, you can specify your own regex with the  `--typevar-rgx=<regex>` command-line switch <sup>*)</sup>.

Note: As Pierre Sassoulas (the maintainer of Pylint) pointed out in a comment: There is no PEP-8 convention (yet) for typevar naming; instead the PyLint team captured the rules observed in Python projects and the type hinting documentation. The exact rule is therefore still subject to change if an official convention were to be created.

---

<sup>*)</sup> The Visual Studio Code settings for the Python extension include a `python.linting.pylintArgs` option that takes a list of command-line switches.

<sup>✝)</sup> *PascalCase* is also known as *CapitalizedWords*, *UpperCamelCase* or *StudlyCase*. Don't confuse this with *camelCase* (initial letter lowercase) or *snake_case* (all lowercase with underscores). I regularly do! When in doubt, Wikipedia has a [handly table of multi-word formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Examples_of_multiple-word_identifier_formats).

Comment: ``camelCase`` is ``likeThis``, ``SeqFr`` is ``PascalCase``. So I would say to sum up that typevar are expected to be pascal case that can be protected or private with ``T``, ``_co``, or ``_contra`` at the end. This is a convention that the pylint team created from what we saw was done in other project, but this is not explicit in PEP8 yet (so it can change if an official convention is created).

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas: you are entirely correct! I don't know how I confused the two this morning. Doh! :facepalm: And yes, I now dragged the wrong name 'snake_case' through the mud too. I need caffeine, clearly

Comment: I created an regex101 so you can easily check your TypeVar names against the rule from the pylint source code: https://regex101.com/r/1Hja8E/1